# Retrieve value from object based on sub-value?

Tags: javascript, object

Say I have an object like so...

```
object = {
    thing0:{
        date: 'Sat, 05 May 2012 01:00:00 EST'
    },
    thing1:{
        date: 'Sat, 05 May 2012 12:00:00 EST'
    },
    thing2:{
        date: 'Fri, 04 May 2012 06:00:00 EST'
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve the `thing` that has the latest date. How could I create a function to quickly compare and retrieve this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no shortcut, you'd need to do a [`for..in`](http://es5.github.com/#x12.6.4) loop to loop over the property names, and check each thing's `date`.

Comment: ah ok, thought there might be a faster way to build a comparator. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
obj = {
    thing0:{
        date: 'Sat, 05 May 2012 01:00:00 EST'
    },
    thing1:{
        date: 'Sat, 05 May 2012 12:00:00 EST'
    },
    thing2:{
        date: 'Fri, 04 May 2012 06:00:00 EST'
    }
}

key_with_max_date = Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) {
    return [new Date(obj[k].date), k];
}).sort().pop()[1]
```

Docs: [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)